# UIViews, subviews and alpha

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, uikit, uiimageview

I have three views on top of each other inside a superview.

```
superview
 - subview 1 (CD Case)
 - subview 2 (Artwork)
 - subview 3 (Shine)
```

when I animate the alpha property of the superview it seams to affect the alpha of all subviews i.e. while the animation is running subview 1 the CD Case shines through the artwork.

While blending all three into one UIImage solves this problem, but for performance reasons this not really an option. (The views are display in a grid view and loaded on demand.)

Is there any other way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: One of the options is to put a black (or some other color) cover on top with zero-alpha. Then fade it in.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can either reverse the fade, as suggested by @debleek63. Or you can change the `shouldRasterize` flag on the superviews layer.

`myView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES`

This will make it use 'group opacity' and everything should composite as you'd expect. The first way is probably more performant, but not as 'correct'.

Comment: Actually scrolling performance is slightly better when using rasterization. Also you need to set `myView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];` to avoid blurry images on a retina display.

Comment: Your answer saved me a lot of trouble. Very nice way to achieve group opacity.